# Como extraer un valor de una URL JSON a PHP dándole un formato?

Tags: php, array, json

Hola tengo una URL de una api, la cual al consultarla me arroja esto:

```
  {
  "status": "Ok",
  "rule": {
    "id": "6181",
    "name": "Andres",
    "deny_countries": [
     "AR",
     "ES",
     "CO",
     "MX"
     ],
    "protocols": [
      "HLS",
      "RTMP",
      "PD"
      ]
     }
    }
```

Lo que deseo es imprimir en un archivo php lo que contiene "deny_countries" que es un arreglo que cambia constantemente, son códigos de paises que quisiera que en el php se visualizaran ya como el pais en sí, ejemplo:
"AR"       Argentina
"ES"       España
"CO"       Colombia
"MX"       México

Muchísimas gracias de antemano!

Este es el codigo php que uso:

```
   <?php
    $url = 'https://api.algo.com/v1/algo';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $rule = json_decode($data);
    echo $rule->deny_countries[0];
    ?>
```

Este es el codigo actualizado, basado en lo que me recomendaste.

```
              <?php
               $url = 'https://api.algo.com/v1/algo';
               $data = file_get_contents($url);
               var_dump($data->rule->deny_countries);
                ?>
```

Comment: Hola puedes agregar el código con el que haces la lectura de estos datos y de paso nos dices como se llama la variable que los guarda? es importante para darte una buena respuesta.

Comment: Echale un ojo a [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), esta funcion de **php** te ayudara a parsear el **json** que traes desde ese **endpoint** a un **array asociativo**, cuando le pasas como primer parametro el json y como segundo parametro el valor `true`

Comment: Hola a ambos @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent y Josbert muchas gracias por contestar, he estado haciendo pruebas, pero no he tenido suerte de obtener ni los datos, el ultimo test que hice fue en https://panelcws.com/axel/decode.php y me sale error Oarray, no soy muy experimentado, seguire investigando, muchas gracias.

Comment: deberías agregar el código asociado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent

Comment: listo @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok el problema es que no estas navegando correctamente en las propiedades:

```
<?php

$json_String ='{"status":"Ok","rule":{"id":"6181","name":"Andres","deny_countries":["AR","ES","CO","MX"],"protocols":["HLS","RTMP","PD"]}}';

$data =  json_decode($json_String);
    
var_dump($data);

var_dump($data->rule->deny_countries[0]);
```

si vez te saltaste la propiedad rule asumiendo que si la variable declarada se llama igual tomara ese dato !!!

```
output #1: 

 object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "Ok"
  ["rule"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "6181"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Andres"
    ["deny_countries"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "AR"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "ES"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "CO"
      [3]=>
      string(2) "MX"
    }
    ["protocols"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "HLS"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "RTMP"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "PD"
    }
  }
}
```

```
output #2: 

string(2) "AR"
```

Comment: Gracias Arcanis el omnipotente ya vi tu codigo, gracias, me ayudo a entender que me estaba saltando la propiedad rule, quise usar este codigo para obtenerlo por medio de la url que es como lo usare y me sale null, que estoy haciendo mal?

               <?php
               $url = 'https://api.algocom/v10f543dd';
               $data = file_get_contents($url);
               var_dump($data->rule->deny_countries);
               ?>

Comment: te saltas el $data = json_decode($data);

Comment: Correcto Arcanis, ya obtengo con var dump en https://panelcws.com/axel/decode.php mi array de deny_countries, ahora investigare para darle formato, y que los strings se visualizen como paises, y no como su clave, gracias.